# Travis CI says JRE is 11 but still won't run JAR of class file version 55

Tags: java, build, continuous-integration, travis-ci, sudo

I have a Python application wired up to a Travis CI build. After the tests run, I need to spin up the application and then run a JAR file to complete testing. The JAR file was compiled with Java 11 and is of class file version 55. In my build, I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/myApp/main/Main has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:495)
```

*EDIT*: Added rest of exception

To check the Java version in the Travis instance, I have a `java -version` line that returns the following:

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "11.0.2" 2019-01-15
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9, mixed mode)
```

So why is the exception acting like the Travis instance is running an earlier version of Java? I had this  same problem locally and was able to fix it by changing my JRE from Java 8 to 11 and never had any problems after that. Is the `java -version` command not tell me the JRE version like I think it is? Is there a way I can change the JRE of the Travis instance by using the `.travis.yml` file?

If necessary, here's the relevant parts of `.travis.yml`:

```yaml
after_script:
  - chmod +x ~/build.sh
  - chmod 777 ./tests/LPT/myApp.jar
  - bash ~/build.sh
  - java -version # output of this is shown in question
  - sudo java -jar ./tests/LPT/myApp.jar ./tests/LPT/input.json 
^ Last line triggers the exception shown in question
```

Comment: You're not showing the output of `sudo java`.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- are you talking about the output of `sudo java -jar blah-blah-blah`? If so, I updated my question to include the whole output though it looks like I left out `Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again`, though that doesn't seem like it would shed a lot of light on the situation

Comment: No, I meant that you're running `java -version` but `sudo java -jar`. Those might not produce the same results.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- omg dude that was it and all I had to do was NOT `sudo` the `java -jar` call aaaaAAAHHHHH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sudo`'s default policies generally clear a lot of environment variables for security reasons, and while you're *building* your application and running your `java -version` check with normal permissions, you're using `sudo java` to actually run it. You may be getting a different `PATH` and/or `JAVA_HOME` in the two environments.